# AutoClick not working with timedout and each

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement where i want to force click with delay.
I want to trigger click event after a delay with each loop.

```
var j = 0;
$(".classname").each(function(index) {
setTimeout(function(){
  j = j + 1000;
  $(this).click();
},j);
});
```

I dont understand why its wont work. Click is not happening atall.
However if i remove delay then its working.

```
var j = 0;
$(".classname").each(function(index) {

  j = j + 1000;
  $(this).click();

});
```

Comment: `console.log(this)` in the timeout and see what it is

Comment: `$(this)` is in the wrong context.

Comment: Its printing [object Window] in 1st case while in 2nd case its printing perfect

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio please help than with answer

Comment: @BrainTeasers there you go

Comment: Yep, because functions change what `this` references.  You'll want to either save it off, bind it to the function, or use an arrow function that doesn't change the scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this)` scope is different for each function.

You should "save" your reference in a variable, and then use it inside the timeout function:

```
var j = 0;
$(".classname").each(function(index) {

  var x = $(this); // LET's STORE this IN x

  setTimeout(function(){
    j = j + 1000;
    $(x).click();
  },j);
});
```

Comment: `x` is already a jQuery object, so `$(x)` is unnecessary.  Also the `each` should accept the element in as the second argument, so you could use that rather than a new local variable

Comment: @Taplar I agree with your `jQuery.each` observation, passing `(index, element)` is definitely more clear and clean